# Proving $a\le f(a)$ for a monotonically increasing function on a well-ordered set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, ordinals, well-orders

> Let $(x,\le)$ be well-ordered set and let $f: \ x \rightarrow x$ be monotonically increasing function.
>
> Prove that $\forall a \in x$ $$a \le f(a)$$
>
> Find an example of set $x$ linearly ordered such that the statement doesn't hold.

**My try:**

Assume $X=\{a \in x \ : \ a \ge f(a) \}$ is non-empty set with a minimal element S (we can assume that there is such element, because the set is well ordered).

According to the definition of set $X$ we know that $S\ge f(S)$, but $f(S)$ is in X, thus we found an element smaller than S and that is contradiction.

It seems too easy and I made no use of monotone characteristic of the function.

I have no idea of how to find proper example and what I need to do to complete the proof.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt is almost fine.

1. $X$ should be $\{a\mid a>f(a)\}$, rather than $\geq$.
2. Monotonity comes into play where you claim that $f(S)$ is $X$ and therefore larger than $S$. You can use it in a clearer manner by pointing out that $S>f(S)>f(f(S))$ and therefore $f(S)$ should be the minimum of $X$ rather than $S$.

Finally, as an example, consider the integers, and something which shifts everything down. Any other linear order which is unbounded from below will do as well (although you can find examples which do have a minimum too).

Comment: As always, your answers are great and useful. Thanks a lot!
After looking a bit in forum I found this link - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446559/if-w-is-a-well-ordered-set-and-f-w-rightarrow-w-is-an-increasing-func?rq=1, so it seems like my question is a duplicate... what do you do in such case?

Comment: Why is $f(S)$ in $X$?

Comment: I think $f(S)\not\in X$ because $S$ is the minimum of $X$, hence $f(S)\le f(f(S))\;\color{blue}{(*)}.$ On the other hand, from monotony, we get that $S>f(S)\implies f(S)>f(f(S))$ but it contradicts $(*)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Angelo: If $S=\min X$, or generally, just $S\in X$, then by definition $f(S)<S$, and therefore $f(f(S))<f(S)$, and therefore $f(S)\in X$.

Comment: You are right. But what about my proof? Is it correct?