# Bernstein- Schroeder thm for ordered sets

Tags: order-theory

Hi everyone the I know that the Bernstein- Schroeder Thm says that if we have two sets $A,B$, and there exists an injection $f: A\rightarrow B$ and $g: B\rightarrow A$, then there exists a bijection $h: A\rightarrow B$.

So my question is regard to ordered sets. What happen if $f,g$ are ordered preserving mappings, this of course not sufficient to conclude that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic, for example in the total case immediately one can think in  the closed and open interval on the real line to say something. So there exists a sufficient and necessary condition to guarantees that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One sufficient (but not necessary) condition is that $A$ and $B$ are *well-ordered* sets. I don't know of any necessary conditions.

Comment: So, if  $A$ and $B$ are well-ordered sets, and if there exists morphisms $A$ to $B$ and $B$ to $A$, hence there exists an isomorphism between $A$ to $B$. Could you give a sketch of the proof or a link, please? Thank

Comment: I don't know if the following is correct but using transfinite induction we can show that there exists at most one morphism from one well-ordered set to another. Then the composition $g\circ f$ give us one morphism from $A$ to $A$, and the identity map on $A$ is a morphism, then $g\circ f = id $, something like this is what I thought. This topic is so interesting :)

Comment: You're close, but not quite there. For example, there are infinitely-many order-preserving maps $A\to\Bbb N,$ when $A$ is a finite well-ordered set. What we *can* show is that if $A$ is a well-ordered set, then the only order-preserving map $A\to A$ is the identity map. Hence, if we have order-preserving maps $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ for some well-ordered sets $A$ and $B,$ then since $g\circ f:A\to A$ is readily order-preserving, it follows that $g\circ f$ is the identity map on $A,$ from which we can deduce that $g=f^{-1},$ and in particular that $f$ is a bijection, so an isomorphism.

Comment: We can further extend that to show that for well-ordered sets $A$ and $B,$ there is at most $1$ isomorphism $A\to B.$ Indeed, if $f_1,f_2:A\to B$ are isomorphisms, then putting $g=f_2^{-1},$ we find that $g\circ f_1:A\to A$ is order-preserving, so is the identity map, so $$f_1=g^{-1}=\left(f_2^{-1}\right)^{-1}=f_2.$$

Comment: Incidentally, there's no real need to (explicitly) use transfinite induction to prove these results. All we need to know is that a non-empty subset of a well-ordered set must have a least element. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632655/is-the-identity-function-the-only-order-preserving-isomorphism-between-a-well-or/632673#632673) for more.

Comment: "there are infinitely-many order-preserving maps $A\rightarrow N$, when A is a finite well-ordered set." Oh Right, but If we add the hypothesis that the ordered preserving map also map $A$ into an initial segment of $\mathbb{N}$, I think is sufficient to guarantees the uniqueness.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly true. We can even use the same result mentioned above to prove it. If $f,g:A\to B$ are order-preserving maps mapping $A$ to an initial segment of $B,$ then without loss of generality, the image of $f$ is an initial segment of the image of $g.$ Letting $C$ be the image of $g,$ then $f\circ\left(g^{-1}\right):C\to C$ is an order-preserving map, whence again $f=g$ as above.

Comment: I'm thinking in all these things, and it's possible generalize what I said above: If we assume that $A,B$ are well-ordered sets and say $f,g: A\rightarrow B$ are strictly monotone functions, which maps $A$ to an initial segment of $B$. Then they are equal. So I think maybe using transfinite induction I can show what I thought first. Let $X$ be a well-ordered set. (Successor case) If $x\in X$ and $P(x)$ is true, then $P(\text{succ}(x))$ is true. (Limit Case) If $x= \text{sup}([\text{min}(X),x))$ and $P(y)$ is true for all $y<x$, then $P(x)$ is true. Then $P(x)$ is true for all $x\in X$.

Comment: So, we need to show that $f,g$ agree on $[\text{min}(A), a)$ for all $a\in A\oplus \{\infty \}$. I don't know if is correct but if we assume that $\forall x\in [\text{min}(A), a)$ $f(x)=g(x)$ we have to show that agree when $a$. So, let $s= \text{sup}([\text{min}(A), a))$. Then either $s\in [\text{min}(A), a)$ or $s\notin [\text{min}(A), a)$. For the former then $s$ is a maximal element, and then $a=\text{succ}(s)$ and so $f(a)=f(\text{succ}(s))=\text{succ}(f(s))=\text{succ}(g(s))=g(\text{succ}(s))=g(a)$ as desired. Now if $s\notin [\text{min}(A), a)$, then $s=x$, so $x$ is a strict sup.

Comment: and so $f([\text{min}(A), a))=g([\text{min}(A), a))$. If we can show that $f(a)$ is the $sup$ of $f([\text{min}(A), a))$ we're done since also $g(a)$ is the sup and by uniqueness follows. Let $s= \text{sup}(f([\text{min}(A), a)))$ and clearly $f(a)$ is an upper bound hence $f(a)\ge s$. If $f(a)>s$ so $s\in f([\text{min}(A), a)$ and then $s= f(x)$ for $x\in [\text{min}(A), a)$. We claim that $succ(x)< a$, if were not the case then $succ(x)\ge a$, if $succ(x)= a $ is a contradiction and similarly if $succ(x)> a$. Thus $succ(x)< a$ and so $f(succ(x))< f(a)$

Comment: so $f(\text{succ}(x))=\text{succ}(f(x))\in f([\text{min}(A), a))$ and also $f(x)=s< \text{succ}(f(x))$ which contradicts that $s$ an upper bound. Therefore $f(a)=s$. Similarly $g(a)=\text{sup}(g([\text{min}(A), a)))$. Since both sets are clearly equal hence $f(a)=g(a)$ as desired. So either the succesor as limit case are true. Hence always holds. Am I totally off track? :P Sorry are very excited with all this things :)

Comment: Looks fine to me, though you omitted the (easy) base case, and the fact that $f\bigl(\operatorname{succ}(s)\bigr)= \operatorname{succ}\bigl(f(s)\bigr)$ needs a bit of justification. Glad to see your enthusiasm! I hope you do see, though, that the approach I recommended is far less tedious and "brute force."

Comment: Absolutely, is easier your approach just shows that the only morphism to a well-ordered set to itself is the identity, which require a little argument by contradiction an we're done. The base case I think is not necessary at all, because is subsume in the limit case, although is customary to use it. Thanks for all your help :)